# How to find biggest sum of items not exceeding some value?

Tags: python, algorithm, mathematical-optimization, knapsack-problem, greedy

How to find biggest sum of items not exceeding some value? For example I have 45 values like this: 1.0986122886681098, 1.6094379124341003, 3.970291913552122, 3.1354942159291497, 2.5649493574615367. I need to find biggest possible combination not exceeding 30.7623.

I can't use bruteforce to find all combinations as amount of combination will be huge. So I need to use some greedy algorithm.

Comment: by biggest combination, you mean that the sum would be biggest (i.e. close as possible to the limit) or you want the most amount of numbers as possible?

Comment: for example, for numbers 2.0,2.0,4.1 and limit 5. you want (2.0, 2.0) or (4.1) ?

Comment: I need biggest sum to as close as possible to the limit. From set 2,2,4,1 I want (4,1). I forgot to mention that all items in my list are unique.

Comment: one thing you can take sum and subtract the lower one by one till it come to limit

Comment: Could you post an actual data set? I'd like to play around with this.

Comment: 0.69314718056 1.09861228867 1.60943791243 1.94591014906 2.3978952728 2.56494935746 2.83321334406 2.94443897917 3.13549421593 3.36729582999 3.43398720449 3.61091791264 3.7135720667 3.76120011569 3.85014760171 3.97029191355 4.07753744391 4.11087386417 4.20469261939 4.26267987704 4.29045944115 4.36944785247 4.4188406078 4.48863636973 4.5747109785 4.61512051684 4.63472898823 4.67282883446 4.69134788223 4.72738781871 4.84418708646 4.8751973232 4.91998092583 4.93447393313 5.00394630595 5.01727983681 5.05624580535 5.09375020081 5.11799381242 5.1532915945 5.18738580584 5.19849703127

Comment: limit: 83.736017050546664

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an instance of the [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). It is [NP-hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard), so with 45 items, you'll have to use some heuristic algorithm ([Hill Climbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing), for example) to find an acceptable estimate. To find the optimal solution, you have no other option than to try all possibilities (which is infeasible). Knowledge of your distribution might change that. If many of the items by themselves would exceed the limit, they could be discarded. Or if the limit would be very close to the sum of all numbers, you might need only a combination of up to about 5 items to not be included; 45 choose 5 is still feasible.

Comment: Thanks for answer. My items are not exceeding limit and much smaller then a limit. Limit is close to the sum if I take just half of items.

Comment: @user1209304 That won't buy you much. Even if you would know for sure that you need exactly 22 items, 45 choose 22 is still 4.1167154e+12; not infeasible but large enough to be impractical (not worth it). I suggest you try Hill Climbing.

Answer (score 0):

What you search for is the knapsack problem I guess. Does this solution help you?

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem/Unbounded/Python_dynamic_programming

Have a look at the solution under "1.2 DP, single size dimension". I think this is not brute force. You should be able to adapt it to your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I have already seen this algorithm. This algorithm works with integers and I have float. So I don't know how to adapt it. For example this algorithm using range(0, C+1)] that does not work with float.

Comment: @user1209304 So what is your problem at the moment? That finding an estimate is not good enough, or that you don't know how to implement such algorithm?

Comment: I don't know how to implement such algorithm.

Comment: @user1209304 There are many online resources about combinatorial optimization (the subject of finding estimates where optimal answers are out of reach) and Hill Climbing in particular. The algorithm is fairly simple; it's worth learning about and trying yourself. Ask a specific (new) question about it when you get stuck at some point.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find approximate solution:

```
Multiply your floats by appropriate number (for example, 100), do the same for sum.
Round floats to the nearest integers (or Ceil them to larger integers)
like Round(1.0986122886681098 * 100) = 110
Solve subset sum problem for integers with DP
Check that sum of floats doesn't excess the limit 
(due to rounding errors)
```

If you have a lot of very close float numbers, you might want to refine solution with optimisation algorithms (like mentioned Hill Climbing)

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be phrased as a zero-one assignment problem, and solved with a linear programming package, such as GLPK, which can handle integer programming problems. The problem is to find binary variables `x[i]` such that the sum of `x[i]*w[i]` is as large as possible, and less than the prescribed limit, where `w[i]` are the values which are added up.

My advice is to use an existing package; combinatorial optimization algorithms are generally very complex. There is probably a Python interface for some package you can use; I don't know if GLPK has such an interface, but probably some package does.